# Extracting text regions from an Image using contours - Opencv , Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, tesseract

I have been working on an OCR project for business cards using opencv in python.

Till now, I have been able to crop the card of the image. I am trying to detect text regions in the cropped image using contours.
(ie, Taking a Canny image , finding contours from those edges and dilating them to get connected components, which must potentially be text regions).

While I was trying to detect closed connected components,some contours cover an extra part(like symbols) apart from the text like in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OZVT.jpg) image.

Due to this,Applying tesseract-ocr on those text regions gives unwanted text(garbage) along with the required text.This is result of my OCR.

**(P) (972) 656-6074
(F) (972) 656-6077
(M) (214) 505-8473
5910 N. Central Expressway, Suite1625»
Dallas, Texas 75206
ken.shulman@capviewpartners.com
WKw™/"
CAPVIEW

EPARTNERS
Ken Shulman, CRE
Partner**

I tried modifying the dilating factor but the part of symbol in the image always becomes a part of the text region.

I want to make the pre-processing as optimized as possible so that tesseract-ocr doesn't make any mistakes.So how to remove those extra parts(symbols) from the text regions or is there an alternate approach ?

Comment: Did you move to some other tool or found any luck in your existing approach for getting the text inside cleanly through OCR? Can you give some details about how you did what you explained above? Thx